# Should the Chat-Rooms Like "JEE Preparation" Be Banned?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that a chat-room called "JEE Preparation" has been made on Physics SE. For those who are not familiar with the JEE, it is short for "Joint Entrance Examination"--which is an entrance exam organized by (and for admissions to) the Indian Institutes of Technology. I think that the core idea of any such group is at odds with the core ideology of Physics SE. I think that the point of Physics SE is to discuss physics and only that. We remove every little thing that gets even slightly diverted from this line. For example, low-quality homework questions, history questions, metaphysics questions, purely philosophical questions, purely mathematics questions--all these are almost always removed from the website. And that is one of the pivotal things that make Physics SE so good. A channel with the sole motive of preparing for an exam which is not even a proper physics exam but rather an engineering entrance exam seems completely unacceptable. That is why I strongly feel that it should be banned.

---

*I have edited the question only to fix a few linguistic issues. I don't intend to revive the question--I still agree with the answer by ACuriousMind which I have had accepted.*

Comment: The JEE Preparation room helps keep the main chat room free from lengthy discussions on JEE related problems. There is a JEE Preparation room at Mathematics SE too. Countless JEE applicants log in to the main chat room everyday. The JEE Preparation room effectively keeps topics which are uninteresting for most of the users of the main chat room away from the main chat room. In fact, the JEE preparation room was created after continous protests from the*The h Bar* users against the extensive JEE related discussions that were happening in their room.

Comment: To put things in perspective, the main chat room has around 1200 new messages every day on average. the JEE preparation room has over 600 new messages every day on average.  That is literally half of the main chat room's activity. If not for the JEE preparation room, JEE discussions would flood the main chat room with JEE centric messages which would be very annoying for most of the users.

Comment: [jee rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/jee-preparation) ([second room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48921/the-jee-launchpad) ) are not only for  jee aspirants .Anyone who is interested in Physics , chemistry and mathematics can chat there .

Comment: I'd like to know your point of view. Do you really think that banning the chat room will improve the site in some way or the other? I'm curious. Keep in mind that it is the second most populated chat room after the hbar (at present).

Comment: @blue Popularity isn't relevant in Science. So, keep aside the popularity arguments. Someone would start a chat room on how to be a millionaire and I am sure more people than those in The h Bar would join. It is about what is in the direction of actual physics and what is not. As clearly visible, JEE discussions are not about actually doing physics rather they are about the preparation of an exam - that too an engineering entrance exam. Someone floods The h Bar with the stupid or irrelevant material then the solution is to ban them from The h Bar - not to invite them to create a new chat bar.

Comment: @blue Removing irrelevant material from the Physics SE will certainly improve it. Don't you think?

Comment: @Dvij No, I don't think so. By your logic even the main chat room should be removed as most of the discussions there are not related to physics. Chat is a place meant for hanging out and not only for discussing physics. That is exactly why it is called "the third place".

Comment: @Dvij Chat rooms like JEE Preparations are an integral part of SE network, and should never be banned. It helps all of us involved in the JEE examination.

Comment: Well, now, I am not against the JEE chatroom as I was when I posted the question, but since your logic seems particularly problematic, I decided to respond. As they say, it is very easy to confuse "what ought to be" with "what is" especially when "what is" has turned out in your favor. ;-) I noticed that the JEE chatroom has become quite popular on the PSE and that is why I expressed my concern. So, I don't deny that it has become a significant constituent the PSE - but I don't espouse to the notion that it is good that it is such significant....

Comment: ... Coming to your second point, why should PSE care about helping JEE aspirants? There are hundreds of exams around the globe and PSE is not a site that is supposed to prepare you for your exams. It is supposed to be a place to discuss and learn physics and to do nothing else. There are other places for other causes and purposes.

Comment: But as pointed out in an answer, the chatrooms are supposed to be the 'third place'. So, it is, by design, something that is created to keep the distractive things away from the main PSE. And the JEE chatroom was created to keep the JEE discussions away from the 'The h Bar' chatroom. So, I think I don't care anymore as long as it doesn't affect the main area of the site. So, I don't demand to ban the JEE chatroom anymore, of course.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, such chat rooms should not be banned.**

Chat is a [third place](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) where the users of a site (or of any other site on the SE network!) can meet and discuss...basically anything they like as long as it does not run afoul of things like the [Be Nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/263383). If you drop into our main chatroom, [the h bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), then at any given time you might find people discussing physics, math, food, music, computers, the site itself, or many other topics. It's not restricted to physics, and it never was meant to be.

Chat is the one place in the SE network where it is appropriate to just socialize and have a little fun, or lengthy, opinion-based discussions, or just talk about whatever is on your mind. It *is* removed from the Q&A website as such, and just because you can talk about it in chat does not mean it would be accepted as a question or answer on the main site. I do not see how the presence of such rooms detracts in any way from our main mission.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the purpose of chat-rooms. I suppose all I have to say now is that I dislike that a large number of people take interest in JEE on Physics SE. But, of course, that doesn't imply that such chats should be banned.

Answer (score 7):

Chat is, by design, a "third place". It is the place where people can do all the things that are fun or useful that would detract from the mission of the main site.

Comment: But engineering? Really? Next day, I open a chat room to discuss variations in stock prices. Would that be a healthy practice?

Comment: @Dvij Try it (*opening a room to discuss variations in stock prices*) and see what happens. Most certainly that room will get frozen due to inactivity. The JEE room thrives as a considerable population uses it and the stuff discussed there is useful to a large number of people (atleast 10).

Comment: Frame your stock price room in terms of econophysics and your only problem would be lack of sufficient experts to keep it active.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, I get it now. I misunderstood the purpose of chat-rooms. I suppose all I have to say now is that I dislike that a large number of people take interest in JEE on Physics SE. But, of course, that doesn't imply that such chats should be banned.

Comment: @Dvij D.C. You're not getting the point. They aren't discussing about engineering. They are preparing *for* an engineering entrance examination which comprises of Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics from which of course they are discussing about physics. Nothing bad in discussing about physics on a physics website. And why do you dislike that a large number of people take intrest in JEE here? Take it to be the same reason why people prepare for SAT and Olympiads.

Comment: @Toshu As I already mentioned, I agree with the accepted answer fully and don't advocate for banning any chat room, be it for discussing Kardashians and I wouldn't care. As long as that is clear, I will be happy to indulge with your additional questions. I personally have no exposure to SATs so I can't comment if I'd like people taking an interest in it or not. Olympiads touch upon really good and interesting physics so I'd be thrilled about it. And JEE simply doesn't concern itself with anything that you can say is remotely interesting (as its focus is on spotting engineering talent).